How to give condition labels in Stylegan2-ada
Give condition in network
According to what I saw in the code, the method of giving condition in discriminator is multiply mapped C after flattening

It is true?
Why is this different compared to the normal CGAN that method of giving condition?

I want to know about reason for multiplication, location of multiplication, reason for multiplying only c
